# Determines the origin point of canvas (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to figure out how to know if the origin point of a canvas is at top/left or center/center or whatever.
Maybe a way to get the coordinates of origin point (even if I know the coordinates of origin point at center/center is also 0, 0).

I have several canvas which I convert to image with toDataUrl function. I need to set a background color to these canvas before converting. So to do this :

```
var curContext = curCanvas.getContext('2d');
curContext.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
curContext.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF'; // or random color
curContext.fillRect(0, 0, curCanvas.width, curCanvas.height);
var image = curCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1));
```

These code works with canvas with an origin point at top/left but some canvas (generated by puglin like hypertree) has an origin point at center/center so my fillRect has to be like this :

```
curContext.fillRect(-curCanvas.width/2, -curCanvas.height/2, curCanvas.width, curCanvas.height);
```

So, I need to know for a canvas, what is the origin point to know how use `fillRect` function (x and y arguments).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show some code and what you're trying to do. if you're just asking where the origin is on the canvas, its the top left

Comment: Is this your real question..?? More brief pls

Comment: Ok, sorry guys. Question edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin will only be misplaced if the other code has used a transformation matrix on it.

You can override that transformation matrix by saving the context's current state, setting a new matrix, and then restoring the original state:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);   // identity
// do your drawing
ctx.restore();
```

Newer versions of the Canvas API have `ctx.resetTransform()` and also allow you to query the current transformation matrix but those aren't widely supported yet.

Comment: Awsome, the transformation matrix is what I need. Thank you very much !